# How to expand an image relatively to another object in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have been trying to make a layout expand itself whenever the view more button is pressed. The second title is supposed to have the same box that the first title has. I want to make it so when the user presses the "view more" button, the second title still is below the expanded text from title 1. [layout wireframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ml6A7.png)

Here's my layout code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    >

    <!-- The ActionBar -->
    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_weight="2.43">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/flContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="210dp"
            android:id="@+id/img_chucrute"
            android:background="@drawable/img_chucrute" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/titulo_chucrute"
            android:background="@drawable/chucrute_titulo"
            android:layout_marginTop="227dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:id="@+id/preco_chucrute"
            android:background="@drawable/preco_chucrute"
            android:layout_marginTop="231dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="272dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="309dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/linha_pagkits"
            android:background="@drawable/linha_pagkits"
            android:layout_marginTop="270dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="27dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/titulo_ingredientes"
            android:background="@drawable/ingredientes_titulo"
            android:layout_marginTop="282dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="29dp" />

        <com.example.renan.chefemcasa.ExpandableTextView
            android:id="@+id/lorem_ipsum"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="302dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
             />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="309dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/linha_apagar"
            android:background="@drawable/linha_pagkits"
            android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="375dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="309dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:background="@drawable/linha_pagkits"
            android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="370dp" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible">
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="180dp"
                android:layout_height="50.5dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton11"
                android:background="@drawable/botao_adicionais"
                android:layout_marginTop="517dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="180dp"
                android:layout_height="50.5dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton12"
                android:background="@drawable/botao_finalizar"
                android:layout_marginTop="-51dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>



<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nvView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_view" />
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you want to to expand and collapse a TextView / some multiple Views?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any TextView elements on your layout and the Buttons you have don't seem to have a different purpose than expanding the text. Once you have a the Button and the TextView on your layout, you could just inject extra content (longer text) into the TextView when the button is pressed.

Here is how:

Add the TextView and the Button to your to your layout.xml (you can add text formatting tags, etcetera to fit your needs).

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/text_to_expand"
    android:text="short blah blah blah" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/expand_button"
    android:text="expand" />
```

Then, from your activity, retrieve the Button and the TextView and add the behavior you want.

```
private Button expandButton;
private TextView expandableText;

...

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_init);

    // retrieve the button and the textview from your layout
    expandButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.expand_button);
    expandableText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.expand_button);

    // set button functionality when it is clicked
    expandButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // replace the text in your TextView by new longer content
            expandableText.setText("blah, blah, blah, very long, blah, blah");
        }
    });

    ...
}

...
```

For extra points, if you add this line to the layout containing your TextView, the transition of size will be animated.

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/container"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    ...
/>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of the following libraries :

- https://github.com/Manabu-GT/ExpandableTextView
- https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/969

If you need help with them, let us know.